# Why are these Python processes stepping on each other?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, numpy-ndarray

I have a simulation that runs on multiple processes. They get their input (a NumPy array containing just integers - no nested objects or other arrays) from a queue, and often report results through another queue. The parent process does this:

1 - populates the input queue with a cope of the data for each process:

```
        output_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        input_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

        for _ in range(parallel_populations):
            new_input = {
                'data': np.copy(data_source),
            }
            input_queue.put(new_input)
```

2 - starts each process:

```
        processes = []
        for i in range(parallel_populations):
            process = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_population,
                                              args=(
                                                  input_queue,
                                                  output_queue
                                              ))
            process.start()
            processes.append(process)
```

3 - then, indefinitely, listens to the outputs coming from the output_queue and kills all processes, and restarts them with the new data:

```
while True:
    # kill all processes
    result = output_queue.get(True)
    for i in range(len(processes)):
        processes[i].kill()

    # populate input_queue again with new data:
    for _ in range(parallel_populations):
        new_input = {
            'data': np.copy(result),
        }
        input_queue.put(new_input)

    # finally, start the processes again
    processes = []
    for i in range(parallel_populations):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_population,
                                          args=(
                                              input_queue,
                                              output_queue
                                          ))
        process.start()
        processes.append(process)
```

Note that every time I put that data array in the input_queue, I make a np.copy so that each process has its own copy. The processes modify the data.

If I run only one process at a time, it runs well indefinitely. But if I launch more than one, they corrupt the data in the array as if i had not made copies before putting in the input_queue.

Doesn't `np.copy` create a full copy of the ndarray? Since they have just numbers, I thought this was sufficient.

I also tried using `data = data[:]` before putting into the queue to make a copy, but same results. Lastly, I tried using `copy.deepcopy` even though shouldn't be needed. Same results.

I also tried starting the processes with `forkserver` as well as `spawn` to see if memory isolation improved, but same results.

I can't seem to figure out why are they stepping on each other. I'm on Python 3.8.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure where your problem lies, but you actually don't need to copy anything at all. Anything you put on an mp.Queue is serialized, and different processes get independent copies *because they're different processes* that deserialized the data independently, not because you made a copy beforehand.

Comment: Then it really makes no sense at all.. that's exactly what I thought was going to happen and the reason I created separate processes. This is really bizarre... if I run one process at a time, it never fails. If I run just two, data gets corrupted somewhere between these transfers back to the parent process and to new child processes again.

Comment: The natural place to look is in the code that collects the results from the subprocesses and compiles them into `result`, which you didn't include here. At this point I think you probably need a new question.

Comment: I ended up switching to shared memory instead of queues and the issue went away. Never found what it was but Iĺl just moved forward now. Thanks a lot @hobbs for your help.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.